# vSphere Performance Graphs - 400x Interfaces?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

All of the performance graphs across all hosts and guests in our vmware 4 infrastructure label network traffic on their performance tabs as "Transmitted for 4002", "Transmitted for 4001" etc.  Where is it pulling these 400x names from?

Comment: Are you looking at the performance charts on a host or VM and what performance counters do you have selected?

Comment: It appears the same on both hosts and VMs.  Screenshot; http://i.imgur.com/BEjnJ.png

Comment: I still can't find this performance chart but are you running vCenter or stand alone ESXi servers?

Comment: vCenter 4.1.  Pick any VM or VM host and select the 'Performance' tab in the main window.

Answer (score 2):

These are number showing different virtual adapters in multihomed VMs.I.e. ethernet0 would be object 4000, ethernet1  - 4001

Comment: Makes sense, but where is the 4xxx nomenclature coming from?  Why not eth0, or 3xxx, or ABCD?

Comment: The numbers are device keys.You are welcome to dig into API that may shed some light: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.vm.device.VirtualController.html